# For $a>1$, show that $\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{1+ax} \leq \frac{\sqrt{a}-1}{\sqrt{a}+1}$, $x \geq 1$

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality

I'm self-learning the analysis I "by Herbert Amann" and got stuck in this problem. It's in Chapter IV Taylor's theorem.

> For $a>1$ and $x\geq 1$ show that $$\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{1+ax} \leq \frac{\sqrt{a}-1}{\sqrt{a}+1}$$

This is what I've tried:

Let $f(t)=\frac{1}{1+tx}$ which is convex and,

$f(a) \geq f(1)+f'(1)(a-1)$

so $\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{1+ax} \leq \frac{x}{(1+x)^2}(a-1) \leq \frac{a-1}{4}$

Comment: I believe you can do the following: prove it for $ x = 1 $.  Then I believe the LHS is a decreasing function of $ x $ for $ x > 1 $, so you're done.  Nevermind, I'm wrong.  Ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$f : x \mapsto \frac{1}{1+x} - \frac{1}{1+ax}$$

$f$ is differentiable on $[1, +\infty)$ and
$$f'(x)= -\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}+\frac{a}{(1+ax)^2}$$

so $$f'(x)\geq 0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{a}{(1+ax)^2} \geq \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{a}(1+x) \geq 1+ax \Leftrightarrow \frac{1-\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}-a} \geq x$$

So the maximum of $f$ is
$$f\left( \frac{1-\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}-a}\right) = \frac{1}{1+\frac{1-\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}-a}} - \frac{1}{1+a\frac{1-\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}-a}} = \frac{\sqrt{a}-a}{1-a} - \frac{1-\sqrt{a}}{1-a}$$ $$= \frac{a+1-2\sqrt{a}}{a-1}= \frac{(\sqrt{a}-1)(\sqrt{a}-1)}{(\sqrt{a}+1)(\sqrt{a}-1)}=\frac{\sqrt{a}-1}{\sqrt{a}+1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Isn't Taylor an overkill here? Given is equivalent to

$$\frac{x(a-1)}{(1+x)(1+ax)} \leq \frac{a-1}{(\sqrt{a}+1)^2}$$ or

$$x(\sqrt{a}+1)^2\leq {(1+x)(1+ax)}$$ or

$$xa+2x\sqrt{a}+x \leq 1+x+ax+ax^2$$

or $$2x\sqrt{a} \leq 1+ax^2$$

which is true since $$0\leq (1-x\sqrt{a})^2$$ and we didn' t even use $x>1$, but it must be $> -{1\over a}$.

Comment: Even more elementary that my own answer. Taylor is definitely not necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove that $$\frac{ax-x}{(1+ax)(1+x)}\leq\frac{\sqrt{a}-1}{\sqrt{a}+1}$$ or
$$\frac{x(\sqrt{a}+1)}{(1+ax)(x+1)}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}+1},$$ which is true by C-S:
$$\frac{x(\sqrt{a}+1)}{(1+ax)(x+1)}\leq\frac{x(\sqrt{a}+1)}{(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{ax})^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}+1}.$$